# How to get response or pass data from control file to js file in Laravel

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

I want to pass data from control file to js file with laravel and ajax, I have tried but I got error all time, How can I pass just one value or array. In this example I have email, name and country in users table.

**Code Here.**

Control file:

```
public function showData(Request $request)
{
    $userid = User::find($request['userId']);
    $user = DB::table('users')->where('id', '=', $userid )->first();
    return response(.....);
}
```

JS file:

```
.done(function() {
    // pass data or do something . . . 
});
```

Should I use .done or success ? which better ?

Comment: Laravel and PHP are backend programming languages. jQuery and JavaScript are frontend scripting languages. To pass information from PHP to JavaScript, you must use a view to print variables. Your question is too vague to answer correctly.

Comment: Thanks Jaw.sh , I know that about backend and frontend. 
But the quesion is,  . . . . I have request from database, than I get results, so I want to see these results in page using js or jquery.

Comment: `return $userid;` will return a JSON output for the user.  More info: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent

Answer (score 0):

```
  return response()->json($user);
```

i think success is better
and check this
https://github.com/laracasts/PHP-Vars-To-Js-Transformer

its easy to use+ with docs and you can find a tutorial about it in the laracasts